# VBA Sum function with a two conditions

Tags: vba, excel, loops, select, sum

I am very new to VBA and trying to learn all I can from the ground up. Thus far i had no luck writing a code that would sum

[image]

1) Oil production based on a specific "Month" and "Field Name".

So as an example, I want to write an example to would add cells in oil_production row when i select a specific field (e.g "Ubarana") and a specific Month ("January").

So everytime the two conditions are met (field name and period) then start adding all cells in oil production tab. 
I will probably specify two cells in the excel sheet to set the conditions (field name and period).

Thanks again.

Thanks really appreciate it.

Comment: It seems like you can use the `Sumifs` function for this: [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b), without using VBA

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify the values to Sum in Sheet2, Field being in Cell A1 and Month being on B1, then you could enter the following formula on Sheet2 C1, as long as your Sheet with the data is called Sheet1 then the following should work as intended:

`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!J:J,Sheet1!E:E,Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!H:H,Sheet2!B1)`